# floating issues

Tags: css

I am trying to make it such that the layout looks like the following (crude) model lol:

--div----------------
|   label  TextBox   |
|   label  TextBox   |
|   label  TextBox   |
|------------------- |

Here is what I have ...

```
.personalInfo_Form
{
width:600px;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
background-color: White;
}

.addressLabel
{
float: left;
width: 140px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: right;
}

.addressField
{
float: left;
padding: 5px;
}
```

the end result viewing in FireFox is that the rows are offset and not uniform. I have noticed that specifying a very specific width of the div can change the outcome of position which makes sense because it will enforce the floating rule that items cannot overlap by default, thus positioning them beneath one another... However, I would like to design it such that the width of the Div is not a factor in the positioning of the inner elements.

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `clear: both;` or `clear: left;` to your `.addressLabel` style. You will have to make sure that the div continues on beyond the floated elements by either floating the containing div or providing a clearfix.

Comment: Lol, thank you sir. That fixed it. It's ironic. I purchased a really good resource "CSS the definitive guide" and I was just finishing the chapter on floating elements. One of the last items in the chapter was titled Clearing. I only read the first 3 sentences and the fourth explained what clearing does and I just skimmed past it. DOH!

Comment: @Matthew might i suggest putting the textbox IN the label? then put the text for the label on whichever side of the text box you desire it on.  Otherwise, be sure to specify the [for] attribute for accessibility.

Also, there is no book that is as comprehensive (nor as dry) as the actual specification itself: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/.